# Flex Sprite xy Coordinates

Tags: apache-flex

I have a drawing that looks more or less like the attached image.
[image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6ba9f7bb2b.png)

The orange square is the currently selected selected sprite.

The sprites are all draws from coordinates that i receive from XML.

```
var sprObject:Sprite = new Sprite();

sprObject.graphics.beginFill(itemList.c.toString());
sprObject.name = strName;

sprObject.graphics.moveTo(iX, iY);
sprObject.graphics.lineTo(iX2, iY2);
sprObject.graphics.lineTo(iX3, iY3);
sprObject.graphics.lineTo(iX4, iY4);
sprObject.graphics.lineTo(iX, iX);
sprObject.graphics.endFill();
mainUI.addChild(sprObject);     // mainUI is a mx:UIComponent
g_Sprite.push(sprObject);        // array of sprites.
```

What I want to do is the following.
If I'm currently on the orange square and I use my keyboard direction buttons (up/down/left/right).
I want to deselect the current sprite and select the next sprite in the appropriate direction.

The problem I'm having is that I cannot get the x and y coordinates of the drawn sprites.
If I look in the array, the x and y coordinates of the sprites are all 0.
If I can retrieve that I can write an algorithm to determine the next sprite to select.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `localToGlobal` and `globalToLocal` methods of the `DisplayObject` class. Check it out **[here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal())**.